# What does this subprocess code do?

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me what these lines of code do?

```
ok = subprocess.call(["find_info",
                          image,
                          json_file])

if ok == 0:
     with open(image, "rb") as test:
         string = test.read()
```

I have read about subprocess in Python for executing shell commands, however, I'm unsure what this does in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module is for executing *external* programs, not just shell commands.

In this case, it calls the program `find_info` with two arguments, waits for it to finish and returns the program's return value.

I've added a link to the [standard library documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/index.html). You might want to keep that documentation handy when programming with Python.

Comment: there is no reference to find_info on the page so where does it load this problem from?

Comment: @Spike The program `file_info` is an *external program*. Not a Python function.

Answer (score 1):

It runs a command or shell script named "find_info" with 2 arguements: image and json_file (both of which are presumably file names).  Then, if find_info was successful (returned 0), it reads the image.

find_info is probably a shell script or program in either $PATH or the directory that the python script lives in.